# Git repo is having issues

Tags: git

ok so I committed my files after `git add . --all` It apparently deleted my files I just did rather than saved them. Is there any way to recover these files? I tried everything and ended up screwing up my local repository as well. It also is not ever showing any changes when I push to github.

```
M   .DS_Store
M   Gemfile
M   Gemfile.lock
D   app/assets/javascripts/hashtags.js.coffee
D   app/assets/stylesheets/hashtags.css.scss
M   app/assets/stylesheets/profiles.css.scss
M   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
D   app/controllers/hashtags_controller.rb
D   app/controllers/moneytags_controller.rb
M   app/controllers/postings_controller.rb
D   app/controllers/usertags_controller.rb
D   app/helpers/hashtags_helper.rb
D   app/helpers/tags_helper.rb
M   app/models/posting.rb
D   app/views/hashtags/index.html.erb
D   app/views/hashtags/show.html.erb
M   app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
D   app/views/moneytags/index.html.erb
D   app/views/moneytags/show.html.erb
M   app/views/postings/_form.html.erb
D   app/views/postings/_posting.html.haml
M   app/views/postings/index.html.erb
M   app/views/postings/index.json.jbuilder
M   app/views/postings/show.html.erb
M   app/views/postings/show.json.jbuilder
M   app/views/profiles/show.html.haml
D   app/views/usertags/index.html.erb
D   app/views/usertags/show.html.erb
M   config/routes.rb
M   db/migrate/20140301150615_create_postings.rb
D   db/migrate/20140303200423_add_body_to_postings.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305184935_create_supertag_tags.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305184936_create_supertag_taggings.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305214420_create_supertag_hashtags.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305214421_create_supertag_hashtaggings.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305214422_create_supertag_usertags.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305214423_create_supertag_usertaggings.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305214424_create_supertag_moneytags.rb
D   db/migrate/20140305214425_create_supertag_moneytaggings.rb
M   db/schema.rb
D   test/controllers/hashtags_controller_test.rb
D   test/helpers/hashtags_helper_test.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--all` (or `-A`) flag to `git add` means "auto-add any new or changed files, and auto-remove any files that I've manually removed".  Or, more simply: "set up the next commit to look like the working-directory looks now."

The above indicates that when you ran `git add . --all` you had, for instance, an `app/assets/stylesheets/profiles.css.scss` that was different from the `HEAD` commit, but you had no file named `app/assets/stylesheets/hashtags.css.scss`.  So you asked git to please make the next commit have the different `profiles.css.scss`, but not have `hashtags.css.scss`.  You then did a `git commit` so the new commit looks like that.

> Is there any way to recover these files?

Yes.  They're in the old commit.  That's kind of the *point* of commits: each commit has a full and complete copy of your work-tree.

> It also is not ever showing any changes when I push to github.

All a `push` does is send the new commit(s) to the receiving end, and update their branch heads.  In general, this only adds new commits (to remove commits during a push you must push with `--force` or `-f`).  So, each older version of any file is still available in the older commits.

Use `git log` or `git log --all`, or `gitk --all` or some other graphical viewer, to see the old commits.

If you just want to retrieve one file from an old commit, you can use `git show` to see it:

```
git show master~5:app/views/hashtags/index.html.erb
```

will show you what that file looked like "five commits ago on branch master" (the `~5` gives the number of commits to "move back in time", as it were).

To get that version of that one file back in your working tree, and also schedule the old version for going into the "next" commit, use `git checkout`:

```
git checkout master~5 -- app/views/hashtags/index.html.erb
```

(The different syntax for `git show` vs `git checkout` is a bit annoying, but one can get used to it.)

If you want to completely undo your "bad" commit, you can use `git revert`:

```
git revert <bad-commit-ID>
```

This command says: "Compare the commit ID I gave you, to the commit that comes before it.  Whatever changes I made, make the exact opposite change now."  So if you deleted a file, git creates it with its old contents.  If you added some text, git removes that text.  If you deleted a line from a file, git adds that line to the file (in the original place).  If you added a file, git removes it.

You can revert *any* older commit, not just the most recent, although in some cases git may need your assistance.  For instance, let's say that three commits ago (`master~3`) you added two lines to `zorg.txt`, and then in the last commit you changed one of those.  If you now attempt to `git revert master~3`, git will want to delete both lines, but one of them is different now, so it won't be sure what to do.

(Reverting the most recent commit always works, because there are—by definition—no newer changes interfering with backing-out the most recent changes.)

In special cases, you can discard the last commit with `git reset --hard HEAD^`, but there is no going back from this, and if you have pushed (published to others) the bad commit, you will have to force-push the result.  Meanwhile, they may be basing *their* work on the bad commit; they are not expecting it to simply vanish, and you'll be making extra work for them to recover.  So in general it's better to `revert` a published commit, rather than discarding it.  (Revert adds a new commit, so you simply cannot lose anything, you just add more stuff to your Git Borg Collective, as it were.)

(To see how to name commits, look at the [`gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Often it seems easiest to use `git log` to get the raw SHA-1 names—things like `676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094`—and cut-and-paste them with the mouse, if you're using command-line tools.  But it's good to learn names like `master^` and `branch~4` and so on.)